# How does an oauth2 Workflow function in AAOS

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, android-automotive

I'm developing my first AAOS (and even Android) app, so bear with me if there are any noob errors.
So my intention is to develop an app for a music streaming service that has a public API and uses oauth2 for authentication.

- My first idea was to just use a WebView, but Google prohibited using WebViews for oauth2 some time ago. Rightfully so as I understand the reason correctly, as my app could interfere/spy on the login credentials.
- So I'm trying to use a CustomTabsIntent. Unfortunately, this does not work. When calling `customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url))` the "link viewer" app is opened, which only displays the Link as a QR code. So, it looks like the default app to open a link is this "link viewer" (at least in the Volvo Emulator I use for testing)

[image]

Here's a link to the actual Activity https://github.com/jasonwurzel/Deezomatic/blob/master/automotive/src/main/java/com/auto/deezomatic/activities/DeezomaticMainActivity.kt

Please don't look at the state of the code/project, I wanted to get the most annoying hurdle out of the way before starting to really develop ;-)

Comment: [This information](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/limited-input-device#obtaining-oauth-2.0-access-tokens) is for Google OAuth with limited input devices. I can't sure if your music streaming service has similar option or not.